# What does "window" refer to?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Reloaded* (2003), Keymaker speaks about the door which leads to the source:

> Keymaker: Once the door is unprotected, the connection will be
> severed. But another connection must first be made.
>
> Soren: How long will that take?
>
> Keymaker: Exactly 314 seconds.
>
> Man: Just over five minutes.
>
> Keymaker: That is the length and breadth of the **window**.

What does "window" refer to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An opening or window of opportunity as in "we have a window of 1 week to get the project finished"

Here are the definitions of window from [Oxford Languages](https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-en/). Definition #4 is the one you want.

> Window (noun)
>
> 4. **an interval or opportunity for action.** (e.g. "the parliamentary recess offers a good window for a bid")

Comment: You're not wrong, but some additional info would be helpful here.